# How to export MongoDB data to CSV file without unnecessary columns like "$__", "$isNew", "_doc"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, export-to-csv

I am trying to export mongodb data to csv using fs.writeFile. After converting jsontocsv Iam getting columns like "$__", "$isNew", "_doc" along with my original columns.

Actually my original DB consists of keys "email", "phone", "date". But after converting into csv I am getting extra keys "$__", "$isNew", "_doc" which I don't want.

I have written the code as shown below-

```
 "result": [
        {
            "is_deleted": false,
            "_id": "6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04b",
            "email": "stu@gmail.com",
            "phone": "9000123987",
            "date": "1/2/2022",
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "is_deleted": false,
            "_id": "6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04c",
            "email": "pqr@gmail.com",
            "phone": "8009988345",
            "date": "9/3/2022",
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": "1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "is_deleted": false,
            "_id": "6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04e",
            "email": "jkl@gmail.com",
            "phone": "1234567890",
            "date": "5/8/2022",
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": "2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "is_deleted": false,
            "_id": "6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04f",
            "email": "abc@gmail.com",
            "phone": "5431265708",
            "date": "1/4/2022",
            "details": [
                {
                    "id": "2"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

```
  const Json2csvParser = require("json2csv").Parser;

  const json2csvParser = new Json2csvParser({ header: true });
            const csvData = json2csvParser.parse(result);
            console.log(" working");
            fs.writeFile("sample.csv", csvData, function(error) {
            if (error) throw error;
            console.log("Write to csv successfully!");
            });
```

From the above code I am able to convert jsontocsv but along with my original columns getting unwanted columns.

**my output:**
""$__","$isNew","_doc","email","phone","date","details"\r\n"{""activePaths"":{""paths"":{""is_deleted"":""default"",""_id"":""init""},""states"":{""ignore"":{},""default"":{""is_deleted"":true},""init"":{""_id"":true},""modify"":{},""require"":{}},""stateNames"":[""require"",""modify"",""init"",""default"",""ignore""]},""strictMode"":false,""skipId"":true,""selected"":{},""fields"":{},""exclude"":null}",false,"{""is_deleted"":false,""_id"":""6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04b"",""email"":""stu@gmail.com"",""phone"":""9000123987"",""date"":""1/2/2022"",""details"":[{""id"":""1""}]}","stu@gmail.com","9000123987","1/2/2022","[{""id"":""1""}]"\r\n"{""activePaths"":{""paths"":{""is_deleted"":""default"",""_id"":""init""},""states"":{""ignore"":{},""default"":{""is_deleted"":true},""init"":{""_id"":true},""modify"":{},""require"":{}},""stateNames"":[""require"",""modify"",""init"",""default"",""ignore""]},""strictMode"":false,""skipId"":true,""selected"":{},""fields"":{},""exclude"":null}",false,"{""is_deleted"":false,""_id"":""6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04c"",""email"":""pqr@gmail.com"",""phone"":""8009988345"",""date"":""9/3/2022"",""details"":[{""id"":""1""}]}","pqr@gmail.com","8009988345","9/3/2022","[{""id"":""1""}]"\r\n"{""activePaths"":{""paths"":{""is_deleted"":""default"",""_id"":""init""},""states"":{""ignore"":{},""default"":{""is_deleted"":true},""init"":{""_id"":true},""modify"":{},""require"":{}},""stateNames"":[""require"",""modify"",""init"",""default"",""ignore""]},""strictMode"":false,""skipId"":true,""selected"":{},""fields"":{},""exclude"":null}",false,"{""is_deleted"":false,""_id"":""6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04d"",""email"":""nvu@gmail.com"",""phone"":""9567823456"",""date"":""7/9/2022"",""details"":[{""id"":""1""}]}","nvu@gmail.com","9567823456","7/9/2022","[{""id"":""1""}]"\r\n"{""activePaths"":{""paths"":{""is_deleted"":""default"",""_id"":""init""},""states"":{""ignore"":{},""default"":{""is_deleted"":true},""init"":{""_id"":true},""modify"":{},""require"":{}},""stateNames"":[""require"",""modify"",""init"",""default"",""ignore""]},""strictMode"":false,""skipId"":true,""selected"":{},""fields"":{},""exclude"":null}",false,"{""is_deleted"":false,""_id"":""6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04e"",""email"":""jkl@gmail.com"",""phone"":""1234567890"",""date"":""5/8/2022"",""details"":[{""id"":""2""}]}","jkl@gmail.com","1234567890","5/8/2022","[{""id"":""2""}]"\r\n"{""activePaths"":{""paths"":{""is_deleted"":""default"",""_id"":""init""},""states"":{""ignore"":{},""default"":{""is_deleted"":true},""init"":{""_id"":true},""modify"":{},""require"":{}},""stateNames"":[""require"",""modify"",""init"",""default"",""ignore""]},""strictMode"":false,""skipId"":true,""selected"":{},""fields"":{},""exclude"":null}",false,"{""is_deleted"":false,""_id"":""6317ffaeccc43ae16856d04f"",""email"":""abc@gmail.com"",""phone"":""5431265708"",""date"":""1/4/2022"",""details"":[{""id"":""2""}]}","abc@gmail.com","5431265708","1/4/2022","[{""id"":""2""}]""
}

[MY CSV EXPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VD8vY.png)

**expected output:**
Need to delete unnecessary columns("$__", "$isNew", "_doc") from the above output

[EXPECTED CSV EXPORT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oodd.png)

Any help on how can I achieve this would be helpful.

Comment: Remove those links, and put your output and expected output (for a _small set of data_, because people don't need to see your entire project, just a [mcve] of the code that's going wrong on just enough data to show that off) [in your post](/help/how-to-ask), and show what `result` is (because there is no indication it's actually mongo related atm. And then also mention _which library you're using_ for working with mongo, because that matters. (And then of course format your post properly, so no all caps or spurious asterisks, and correctly indented code so folks can read it with ease)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I have edited the above code

Comment: but you're still not saying what `result` _really_ is: _which library are you using_? MongoDB Node Driver? Mongoose? Something else? Because different libraries add different "administrative" variables. As for writing data: just be explicit and don't write "whatever is in `results`", map it to objects with only the properties you need, ordered the way you need them, and then write _that_ out to file.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans I am using mongoose library.

Comment: Then mention that in your post, and add the `mongoose` tag